# Free PDF viewer for different operating systems that supports animations/Javascript

Tags: android, linux, ios, pdf-viewer

I need to be able to view a pdf file that contains animations, and I need to be able to do this on all the common operating systems (Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iPhone). What free programs can display such files correctly?

~edit~ Since no one seems to know the answer, could I get some help testing what works? I just need people to try to open [this test file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bECMHUNmgMAESmtxFETPXQ6QXvcxWmHQ) on their respective operating systems, using their available pdf-readers, and just report back if it works or not. It should take you all of 10 seconds to view the file and confirm this. Please state your operating system, the program you used, and whether or not the file displayed correctly.

~edit2~ I have now found a solution for Windows and Mac systems, but I'm still looking for something that works on Android, iOS and Linux. It's possible there's nothing available at this point in time.

These are the results so far:

- What works:

  - Windows: Adobe Acrobat Reader
  - Mac: Adobe Acrobat Reader
- What doesn't work:

  - Windows: Foxit Mobile PDF
  - Mac: Preview
  - iPhone: the built-in pdf-viewer for Google Drive app
  - Android: Adobe Acrobat Reader, Foxit Mobile PDF reader
  - Linux: eog, okular
  - Other: the built-in pdf-viewers for Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Safari

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: PDF is a terrible format for anything except static representations of paper documents. If you're creating these files, is there a different format you can use, such as HTML?

Comment: The PDF format is a project requirement. It cannot be changed.

Comment: I would find it extremely useful if anyone with a non-windows OS could try to view the above test file in their preferred PDF-viewer and just report whether it works or not. Especially Mac/iPhone users and any Adobe Reader version.

Comment: On Linux Ubuntu 2018.04 the animation does not work with either eog nor okular.

Comment: Thanks, Nicolas. That's useful to know. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul♦ This might be a big ask, but is it possible you could install Adobe Reader on your Linux machine and test that for me? I've been able to recruit friends and colleagues with various operating systems to run a bunch more tests to narrow down my options, but I don't know anyone who has Linux, so that's the only thing I can't test.

Comment: @Ulysses: Adobe Reader for UNIX has not been updated since 2013 so it contains tons of security vulnerabilities. How about you try it on a virtual machine? :-)

Comment: @Nicolas Thanks for the tip! I didn't know that was an option. I'll look into it and see if I can get that set up.